# Passing information to multiple threads in the dining philosopher's algorithm

Tags: c, pthreads, dining-philosopher

I am trying to create multiple threads and pass a different value to each thread for the dining philosopher's problem. But I am getting this error:

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

Here is my code:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond_var;
pthread_t philo[NUM];

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&cond_var, NULL);

    //Create a thread for each philosopher
    for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        pthread_create (&philo[i], NULL,(void *)philosopher,(void *)i);  // <-- error here

    //Wait for the threads to exit
    for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        pthread_join (philo[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}

void *philosopher (void *num)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: pthread_create() takes a pointer not an int.

Comment: I changed  pthread_create (&philo[i], NULL,(void *)philosopher,(void *)i); to  pthread_create (&philo[i], NULL,(void *)philosopher,(int *)i); still doesnot work.....

Comment: Why are you casting `philosopher` to `void *`? That's the wrong type.

Comment: @RADAR: It's absolutely not OK to pass the address of `i`, here. The value of `i` will be totally unpredictable when those threads try to access it, because you only have one variable, which is changing, and access to it is not synchronized. The fact that it'll simply persist is not the issue.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths, you re right

Answer (score 0):

The warning is simply means that an `int` is not necessarily the same size as a pointer on all platforms. To avoid the warning, you could declare `i` as an `intptr_t`. An `intptr_t` *is* guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer. But allow me to suggest an alternative solution.

The code below demonstrates how to start multiple threads while passing a unique piece of information to each thread. The steps are

1. declare an array that has one entry for each thread
2. initialize the array entry for each thread
3. pass the array entry to the thread
4. retrieve the information from the array when the thread starts

In sample code below, we want to pass a single integer to each of the threads, so the array is just an array of `int`. If more information is needed per thread, it would be appropriate to have an array of `struct`s.

The code starts five threads. Each thread is passed a unique ID (an `int` between 0 and 4) which it prints to the console after a short delay.  The purpose of the delay is to demonstrate that the threads will each get a unique ID, regardless of when they start.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM 5
static int infoArray[NUM];    // 1. declare an array with one entry for each thread

void *philosopher( void *arg );

int main( void )
{
    int i; 
    pthread_t threadID[NUM]; 

    srand( time(NULL) );

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM; i++ )
    {
        infoArray[i] = i;     // 2. initialize the array entry for this thread

        // 3. pass the array entry to the thread
        if ( pthread_create( &threadID[i], NULL, philosopher, (void *)&infoArray[i] ) != 0 )  
        {
            printf( "Bad pthread_create\n" );
            exit( 1 );
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM; i++ )
        pthread_join( threadID[i], NULL );

    return( 0 );
}

void *philosopher( void *arg )
{
    sleep( rand() % 3 );

    int id = *(int *)arg;   // 4. retrieve the information from the array
    printf( "%d\n", id );

    return( NULL );
}
```